# How to use NTRU for signature?

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature

I'm looking for NTRU implement by Java,  now I am use BC(bouncycastle). It looks like NTRUSigner was deprecated and no suggest for it.

```java
/**
* Signs, verifies data and generates key pairs.
* @deprecated the NTRUSigner algorithm was broken in 2012 by Ducas and Nguyen. See
* <a href="http://www.di.ens.fr/~ducas/NTRUSign_Cryptanalysis/DucasNguyen_Learning.pdf">
* http://www.di.ens.fr/~ducas/NTRUSign_Cryptanalysis/DucasNguyen_Learning.pdf</a>
* for details.
*/
```

And I found the question in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/how-can-one-sign-with-ntru/2398

That means NTRU is not support signature, or it is not a good idea use NTRU. If not, Please give me some advices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the newer signer is pqNTRUsign, https://github.com/zhenfeizhang/pqNTRUSign

probably not wise to use for anything very serious, bleeding edge and all that